# Laravel 5.6 Eloquent Relationship not returning value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

This is a section of Two of my related models in Laravel

```
class Employee extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $primaryKey = 'employee_id';
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function branch(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Branch');
    }

    public function orders(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
    }
}

class Branch extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey = 'branch_id';
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function employees(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Employee');
    }
}
```

And these are the migrations of the above two models (up function only)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('branches', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('branch_id')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->primary('branch_id');
    });
}


public function up()
{
    Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {     
        $table->string('employee_id')->unique();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('job');
        $table->string('branch_id');
        $table->foreign('branch_id')->references('branch_id')->on('branches')->onDelete('cascade');          
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->primary('employee_id');
    });
}
```

When I run `php artisan tinker` and test out the relationship, I get the following output:

```
 >>> namespace App
 >>> $emp = new Employee()
 => App\Employee {#778}
 >>> $emp = $emp->find('CMB-EMP-001')
 => App\Employee {#787
     employee_id: "CMB-EMP-001",
     name: "FirstName LastName",
     job: "Root",
     branch_id: "CMB",
     created_at: "2018-04-11 17:24:53",
     updated_at: "2018-04-11 17:24:53",
   }
 >>> $emp->branch()->get()
 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#775
     all: [],
    }
```

As you can see, it returns an empty array instead of the branch id of the employee. What have I done wrong?

EDIT:

```
>>> $emp->branch
 => null
```

Comment: What happens if you run `$emp->branch`?

Comment: @Jonathon it returns `null`. I edited my post to show it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the foreign key:

```
class Employee extends Authenticatable
{
    public function branch(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Branch', 'branch_id');
    }
}
```

And use `$emp->branch` instead of `$emp->branch()->get()`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It works now. Should have paid more attention to the documentation.

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as accepted? This shows other users that the issue is resolved.

Comment: sure. Sorry... It didnt let me mark it earlier which is why it was delayed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Change your `belongsTo()` relationship

```
public function branch(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Branch', 'branch_id', 'branch_id');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works now. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To build on Jonas's point, and to provide more clarity for future viewers:

The actual signature for defining a belongsTo relationship is

```
belongsTo(relatedEntity, foreignKey, ownerKey, relationModel)
```

At present, in your use of belongsTo, you're only defining which related entity you are defining a relationship with.  What you need to do is provide details of the owner key (rather than the foreign key), so in your case:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Branch', 'branch_id', 'branch_id');
```

Why is this the case?

Laravel's default behaviour for determining which column to utilise is:

1. For the foreign key, take the related entity name and add the `_id` suffix.  I.e. branch_id
2. For the owner key, default to using "id", since Laravel's convention is that a model's primary key should be called "id".

Given that in your migrations you've modified Laravel's default approach, by naming your primary key "branch_id" rather than just "id", you need to tell Laravel how to relate the two models.